# Typescript overloading unnamed function in trpc

Tags: typescript, overloading, trpc.io

I have a typical trpc route. It fetches `posts`. If there is an id argument, it fetches 1 post. If none, it fetches all posts. What is the syntax for overloading an unnamed function, and where do I put the overload code in this case?

```js
publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({ id: z.string().nullish() }).nullish())
    .query(async ({ input }) => {

      const url = "https://example.com/posts";
      const json = (await got.get(url).json()) as IPosts[];

      if (input && input.id) {
        const posts = json.find(p => p.id === input.id);
        if (posts) return posts;
      }

      return json;
    })
```

Not sure if the below works or is the correct syntax but looking to put something like one of the below to overload the function

```js
type IOverload = {
   (id: undefined): IPosts[];
   (id: string): IPost; 
}

// or

function unnamedFn<T extends string | null>(id: T): T extends string ? IPost : IPosts[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea works fine !

```
type IPost = {};

type IOverload = {
    (id: undefined): IPost[];
    (id: string): IPost;
}

declare const overloaded: IOverload;

overloaded(undefined)
//^? IPost[]

overloaded('')
//^? IPost
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgCgewM7CgXigbwL4G4CwAUEaJLAPIBuEATgDYICGAJulkVJ1ABQCWzALigBXAHbMIAM16iIzAJRD4yYAG0AugUJce-IShoyA5otiIUW7ESISAxnUY1othKJRQE1ekwmCKXhhYtIhc3VEkEBDZPWkDfbjEJaVkFIgB6NJ0APQB%20a0JQ9wiEACZogJ85bgByavl0zK5coiA)